# Access a dynamically generated input in r shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I have an app where the user needs to assign randomly generated elements (in this case, letters) to groups, but gets to decide how many groups to use. Because the `selectInput` where memberships are defined is generated dynamically in response to a number specified by the user, naming the menu is done automatically (e.g., `usergroup1`, `usergroup2`, etc.). I am having trouble accessing the input values and returning them from the module to use later because I won't know in advance how many inputs there will be, and hence how many `usergroups` to call. Here is an example app:

**UI module:**

```
library(shiny) 
library(stringr)

mod1UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    numericInput(ns("n"), "N",value = NULL),
    actionButton(ns("draw"),"Generate Letters"),
    hr(),
    numericInput(ns("groups"), "Enter number of groups (1-3)", value=NULL),
    uiOutput(ns("groupings"))
  )
}
```

What I tried to do here is make a list of `usergroup` names and return those, but the values aren't attached, and nothing comes through.

**Server module:**

```
mod1 <- function(input, output, session, data) {
  ns <- session$ns
  x <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$draw, {
    req(input$n)
    x$data <- sample(letters,input$n)
  })

  output$groupings <- renderUI({
    req(input$groups)
    ltrs <- data()
    lapply(1:input$groups, function(i) {
      selectizeInput(paste0(session$ns("usergroup"),i), 
                     paste0("Select letters for Group ", i),
                     choices=ltrs, 
                     options = list(placeholder = "Select letters for this group", 
                                    onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')), multiple=T)
    })
  })

  gps <- reactiveValues(gps=NULL)

  reactive({
    gps$gps <- lapply(1:input$groups, function(i) { paste0(session$ns("usergroup"),i) })
  })

  return(list(dat = reactive({x$data}),
              groups = reactive({gps$gps})
  ))
}
```

**UI:**

```
ui <- navbarPage("Fancy Title",id = "tabs",
         tabPanel("Panel1",
             sidebarPanel(
                  mod1UI("input1")
             ),
             mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("lettersy")
             )
         )
      )
```

**Server:**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  y <- callModule(mod1, "input1", data=y$dat)
  output$lettersy <- renderText({
    as.character(c(y$dat(), y$groups(), "end"))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Its a little hard for me to follow, if you could provide a totatlly reproducible example I could try to help further. But yes I did get a solution to my old problem. See the question and answer here. Joe's answer might be what you need... https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/shiny-discuss/lapply%7Csort:date/shiny-discuss/VMtWeH--d3o/LC1nJyA-AgAJ

Comment: @TrevorNederlof Joe's answer was helpful for thinking about what to put inside reactive(), but I didn't want to call the whole module over and over - in the end I kept digging around on SO with different search terms and eventually found a couple solutions to similar problems, which eventually worked. Answer should provide a fully working example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution mimics a couple others found on SO, namely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314472/find-the-input-id-of-a-textinput-element-dynamically?rq=1).

The key is to create a `reactiveValues` object and then assign the values using `[[i]]`. In my case it helped to use a submit button to trigger that.

Complete, working code is as follows:

**UI module:**

```
library(shiny)
mod1UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    numericInput(ns("n"), "N",value = NULL),
    actionButton(ns("draw"),"Generate Letters"),
    hr(),
    numericInput(ns("groups"), "Enter number of groups (1-3)", value=NULL),
    uiOutput(ns("groupings")),
    actionButton(ns("submit"), "Submit Groupings")
  )
}
```

**Server Module:**

```
mod1 <- function(input, output, session, data) {
  ns <- session$ns
  x <- reactiveValues(data=NULL)

  observeEvent(input$draw, {
    req(input$n)
    x$data <- sample(letters,input$n)
  })

  output$groupings <- renderUI({
    req(input$groups)
    ltrs <- data()
    lapply(1:input$groups, function(i) {
      selectizeInput(paste0(session$ns("usergroup"),i), 
                     paste0("Select letters for Group ", i),
                     choices = ltrs, 
                     options = list(placeholder = "Select letters for this group", 
                                onInitialize = I('function() { this.setValue(""); }')), multiple=T)
    })
  })

  gps <- reactiveValues(x=NULL)
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    lapply(1:input$groups, function(i) {
      gps$x[[i]] <- input[[paste0("usergroup", i)]]
    })
  })

  test <- session$ns("test")

  return(list(dat = reactive({x$data}),
              groups = reactive({gps$x})
  ))
}
```

**UI:**

```
ui <- navbarPage("Fancy Title",id = "tabs",
          tabPanel("Panel1",
              sidebarPanel(
                  mod1UI("input1")
              ),
              mainPanel(verbatimTextOutput("lettersy")
              )
          )
)
```

**Server:**

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  y <- callModule(mod1, "input1", data=y$dat)
  output$lettersy <- renderText({
    as.character(c(y$groups()))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```