# How to ask R Shiny to create several "select boxes" - based on previous input

Tags: r, shiny

In my tiny Shiny app I am asking the user: how many time periods do you want to cut your time series into? For example, the user selects 3.
I want to use this input to take a fixed vector of dates and make it possible for the user the select from it the desired last date of Time Period 1 (in select box 1), and Time Period 2 (in select box 2). (The last date for time period 3 will be the very last date, so I don't need to ask).

I am not sure how to do it. I understand that because I don't know the desired number of time periods in advance, I have to create a list. But how do I then collect the input from those select boxes?

Thanks a lot!

```
library(shiny)

### UI #######################################################################

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Defining time periods"),

  # Sidebar: 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Slider input for the number of time periods:
      numericInput("num_periodsnr", label = "Desired number of time periods?",
                  min = 1, max = 10, value = 2),
      uiOutput("period_cutpoints")
    ),


    # Show just the number of periods so far.
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("nr_of_periods")
    )
  )
))



### SERVER ##################################################################

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  library(lubridate)

  output$nr_of_periods <- renderPrint(input$num_periodsnr)

    # Define our dates vector:
  dates <- seq(ymd('2016-01-02'), ymd('2017-12-31'), by = '1 week')


  # STUCK HERE:
  # output$period_cutpoints<-renderUI({
  #   list.out <- list()
  #   for (i in 1:input$num_periodsnr) {
  #     list.out[[i]] <- renderPrint(paste0("Sometext", i), ,
  #                                  )
  #   }
  #   return(list.out)
  # })

})

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is similar to a question I asked and subsequently worked out an answer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51531006/access-a-dynamically-generated-input-in-r-shinyZ). The big changes are (predictably) in the server.

Nothing needs to change in the UI, but as you'll see below I've included another `textOutput` so that you can see the dates you end up selecting, and I've also added an `actionButton`, which I'll explain later.

The server function has a couple additions, which I'll describe first and then put together at the end. You're right that you need to create a list of input objects inside the `renderUI`, which you can do through `lapply`. At this step, you're creating as many `selectInput`s as you'll have cutpoints, minus one because you say you don't need the last:

```
output$period_cutpoints<-renderUI({
    req(input$num_periodsnr)
    lapply(1:(input$num_periodsnr-1), function(i) {
      selectInput(inputId=paste0("cutpoint",i), 
                  label=paste0("Select cutpoint for Time Period ", i, ":"),
                  choices=dates)
    })
  })
```

Next, you'll need to access the values selected in each, which you can do in the same way, using a `reactiveValues` object you create first, and assign the new values to it. In my version of this problem, I couldn't figure out how to get the list to update without using an `actionButton` to trigger it. Simple `reactive()` or `observe()` doesn't do the trick, but I don't really know why.

```
seldates <- reactiveValues(x=NULL)
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    seldates$x <- list()
    lapply(1:(input$num_periodsnr-1), function(i) { 
      seldates$x[[i]] <- input[[paste0("cutpoint", i)]]
    })
  })
```

Full working app code then looks like this:

```
library(shiny)

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Defining time periods"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      numericInput("num_periodsnr", label = "Desired number of time periods?",
                   min = 1, max = 10, value = 2),
      uiOutput("period_cutpoints"),
      actionButton("submit", "Submit")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("nr_of_periods"),
      textOutput("cutpoints")
    )
  )
))

server = shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  library(lubridate)

  output$nr_of_periods <- renderPrint(input$num_periodsnr)

  dates <- seq(ymd('2016-01-02'), ymd('2017-12-31'), by = '1 week')

  output$period_cutpoints<-renderUI({
    req(input$num_periodsnr)
    lapply(1:(input$num_periodsnr-1), function(i) {
      selectInput(inputId=paste0("cutpoint",i), 
                  label=paste0("Select cutpoint for Time Period ", i, ":"),
                  choices=dates)
    })
  })

  seldates <- reactiveValues(x=NULL)
  observeEvent(input$submit, {
    seldates$x <- list()
    lapply(1:(input$num_periodsnr-1), function(i) { 
      seldates$x[[i]] <- input[[paste0("cutpoint", i)]]
    })
  })

  output$cutpoints <- renderText({as.character(seldates$x)})
})

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Thank you very much and for the great explanation!

Answer (score 2):

you can make the boxes dynamically inside an lapply and send them as 1 output object to the ui

```
require("shiny")
require('shinyWidgets')

ui = shinyUI(fluidPage(

  titlePanel("Defining time periods"),

  # Sidebar: 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      # Slider input for the number of time periods:
      numericInput("num_periodsnr", label = "Desired number of time periods?",
                   min = 1, max = 10, value = 2),
      uiOutput("period_cutpoints")
    ),


    # Show just the number of periods so far.
    mainPanel(
      textOutput("nr_of_periods")
    )
  )
))


# Define server logic ----
server <- function(session, input, output) {

  output$period_cutpoints<- renderUI({
    req(input$num_periodsnr > 0)
    lapply(1:input$num_periodsnr, function(el) {
      airDatepickerInput(inputId = paste('PeriodEnd', el, sep = ''), label = paste('Period End', el, sep = ' '), clearButton = TRUE, range = F, update_on = 'close')
    })
})

}

# Run the app ----
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Since you did not provide a dataset to apply the inputs on, and I don't know what date ranges your data has, I did not add code to set min/max on the date pickers, and not sure what kind of code to provide for you to use the data. You would need to write something to put them in a list indeed

```
values <- reactiveValues(datesplits = list(), 
previous_max = 0)

observeEvent(input$num_periodsnr, { 
  if(input$num_periodsnr > values$previous_max) {
    lapply(values$previous_max:input$num_periodsnr, function(el) { 
      observeEvent(input[[paste(paste('PeriodEnd', el, sep = '')]], {
        values$datesplits[el] <- input[[paste(paste('PeriodEnd', el, sep = '')]]
      })

    values$previous_max <- max(values$previous_max, input$num_periodsnr)
    })
  }
})
```

and then use the list of dates for whatever you need to do with them I think.

I use the trick with run lap`enter code here`ply from `previous_max` to `input$num_periodsnr`  `if(input$num_periodsnr > values$previous_max){}` to avoid the problem you create when you repeatedly create `observers` for the same `input` `element`. Whereas `ui` elements are overwritten when created in a loop, `observeEvents` are made as copies, so every time your loop fires, you make another copy of `observers` `1:n`. This results in all copies firing every time, until you have a million `observers` all firing, creating possible strange bugs, unwanted effects and loss of speed.